# how to concatenate dataframe selection criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I need to be able to supply a list of conditionals of the form:

```
(df['SalePrice'] >= 50000), (df['SalePrice'] <= 1e10)
```

which I am going to compile from a small list of tuples with a lambda called `byRange`

into a single call, which I think should be roughly like this:

```
df[list(map(byRange, cutoffs))]
```

so that the result acts as a combined selector on the df, like this:

```
df[(df['SalePrice'] >= 50000) & (df['SalePrice'] <= 1e10)]
```

my problem is, how would I concatenate those list elements with a (bitwise '&') operator?

Comment: no I dont think so - cut returns a series. it is dataframe in, dataframe out

Comment: `np.logical_and.reduce`

Comment: @ALollz seems to be replacing all values with True

Comment: Then it must be an issue with how you are generating the True/False values to begin with. The operation is in the function name: `Compute the truth value of x1 AND x2 element-wise.` and with `.reduce` it allows you to chain the `&` between an arbitrary number of inputs.

Comment: an underlying problem is that numpy's logical_and _"Returns: 
y : ndarray or bool "_ and reduce _"Returns: 
r : ndarray"_ -- so an array of bools or of arrays is what you would expect.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the problem. You are trying to slice the `DataFrame` with an `&` between multiple conditions, so you should be using a single Boolean array, with the same length as your `DataFrame`. This is what `np.logical_and.reduce` will provide, given you pass it an array-like of Boolean values.

Comment: no, np.logical_and.reduce will return an ndarray in any case. reduce cannot return any other value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df['SalePrice'].isin(conditions)]
```

In your specific case it would be:

```
df[df['SalePrice'].isin([50000,1e10])]
```

You can read more about isin [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

### EDIT

As pointed out by ALollz My answer is quite wrong in this case. OP didn't ask for an exact match (which is what `.isin()` does). So as mentioned by OP in his comment to this answer `.query()` is actually the way one could go.

```
df.query('SalePrice >= 50000 & SalePrice <= 1e10')
```

Comment: I don't think `.isin` is the appropriate selection here. It's really a `.between` for the provided example, though may need to be more flexible to simply provide `&` between an arbitrary number of Boolean Series.

Comment: this doesn't expand to more than one condition. I am receiving an array of such conditions

Comment: I am getting NaN though.. for example, I generate conditionals: `{'SalePrice': [50000, 10000000000.0], 'GrLivArea': [0, 4000]}` from input and then run `df[df.isin(conditionals)]` and get back a df with every row but all values set to NaN (both columns are present in df)

Comment: I had given this to you but in the end I wasnt able to get this to work as described. However, it did inspire me to read the documentation more and I discovered query, which neatly solves my problem. And-- your answer was great really -- it _should work_, not exactly sure why everything comes back false even when preselecting the columns with `df[[columns]].isin...`

Comment: @robertotomás No worries man. You should post and accept your own answer then. It might be helpful for people having your same problem